# Negative number of events in Sideband subtraction method

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I am referring to the general side-band subtraction method used to separate signal from background distribution using the likelihood fits of signal and background models performed on some discriminatory variable like mass. 
In those cases, how do we explain the final unfolded signal distribution of signal if there are negative events present? Do I have to reweigh all the bins again? How should I tackle this case as I want a distribution of only signal with positive number of events?

Here is a [link](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/viewauth/CMSPublic/SWGuidePhysicsToolsSideBandSubtraction?t=1525186000) which explains side-band subtraction method. 
And corresponding example of plot of pt distribution of signal having such negative number of signal events unfolded by this method.(Here mass was used as the discriminatory variable and hence the title is mass SBS Signal).(This plot is also available on the link I shared above).

[image: plot]

Comment: The question is "what is wrong as far as you are concerned with the plot you show?" the negative numbers just give consistency with zero.

Comment: @annav I am sorry, I did not get this statement :"negative numbers just give consistency with zero". Do I have to scale all the bins? Because if I have MC signal data of pt distribution, how can I compare it with this real data plot? Even if i normalize to same area, the real data plot will always have these negative number of events. My goal is to see how well the unfolded signal pt distribution is and thus I want to compare this real data plot with MC signal data plot ....

Comment: I think that in the plot you show, the addition of a few negatives will be within the error, and not make a difference. Alternatively you can stop using the right side when the numbers become negative. The effect is zero within errors.

Comment: @annav Also, what is the reason that I can not use a discriminatory variable (like mass used in this example) as a control variable(or the variable which we want to unfold like pt in the example) itself?

Comment: "Because if I have MC signal data of pt distribution, how can I compare it with this real data plot? "  I cannot understand  the question, this plot seems like a mass plot. A p_t will be a p_t plot. You acan compare mc signal+background with data signal+data and get the numbers from the monet carlo . If you use the sideband subtraction methot on the montecarlo+signal you should again get negative sidebands. The medthod is a way to avoid dependence on monte carlo. Only using monte carlo you can get the  p_t distribution of the data in the above plot.

Comment: @annav Sorry, Actually my above comment was an independent question on the SBS method. What I was asking is that in the link I shared states that the variable you use for discrimination(like mass in the link) should be different from the variable which has to be unfolded(like they unfolded pt distribution). So I was asking why are variables correlated with the discriminatory variable not allowed in SBS method to be unfolded?

Comment: @annav I asked my Prof about it. He said one could use discriminatory variable as control variable. Anyways, thanks a lot :)

Comment: good luck with your studies. I was going to suggest to ask your professor because it is a specific question only somebody who has used the technique can really advise you.